# xgboost install on tensorflow GPU support

Tags: tensorflow, xgboost

I already install tensorflow GPU support.

try install xgboost on tensorflow by

```
'conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost'
```

I wonder the xgboost what GPU support or not.

I don't install https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-with-gpu-support

only tensorflow GPU support.

Do i need install xgboost Gpu support or not??? if i want use xgboost with GPU support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your xgboost is compiled for gpu, just try to run some model with `tree_method='gpu_hist'` or another gpu method ([here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/)).
If it would raise an error that xgboost's not compiled for gpu, then reinstall it following the [instructions](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-with-gpu-support) that you have found.
Probably, you don't need install CUDA (if you have successfully installed tensorflow-gpu and it works, then CUDA must be installed already), but you definitely should build gpu-supported xgboost.